# Unit Testing ServiceBus.Message. How to set value for SystemProperties.LockToken?

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I want to test a message handler callback that I have registered with a QueueClient using `queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(MyCallBack, messageHandlerOptions)`.

```
public Task MyCallBack(Message msg, CancellationToken token)
{
   // Read msg. Do something

   // Since everything ran fine, complete the msg.
   await _client.CompleteAsync(msg.SystemProperties.LockToken);
}
```

Now as part of my unit test I call `MyCallBack`. Since I pass a *valid* message. I expect `client.CompleteAsync()` to be called. However the test throws an exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
```

This is because `msg.SystemProperties.LockToken` is **not** set (which is because message was not *actually* read from a queue by a client with `ReceiveMode.PeekLock` mode).

Is there a way to set/mock this so that I can run my tests with a dummy string as a token?

PS: I know I can check for `msg.SystemProperties.IsLockTokenSet` before actually accessing the LockToken field; but even in that case I will never be able to unit test if `_client.CompleteAsync()` was called.

Comment: I tried putting a wrapper around `Message`, but that would require putting a wrapper around `SystemPropertiesCollection`. It looks difficult to mock. Perhaps you could extract "do something" into another dependency and pass either the message or its body (the least you can get away with passing) to that. That way you can test that class, and this method won't really do anything worth testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a wrapper method `GetLockToken()` which returns the `LockToken` string if it set on the message, else it returns null (instead of throwing an exception).

```
private string GetLockToken(Message msg)
{
    // msg.SystemProperties.LockToken Get property throws exception if not set. Return null instead.
    return msg.SystemProperties.IsLockTokenSet ? msg.SystemProperties.LockToken : null;
}
```

The original method call to `CompleteAsync()` is now modified to:

```
await _client.CompleteAsync(GetLockToken(message));
```

**Note**: The above change doesn't change the expected behavior! In a production scenario, call to `CompleteAsync(null)` would still throw an exception :) (as desired).

With above changes now I can set up my mocks as such:

```
var mock= new Mock<IQueueClient>();
mock.Setup(c => c.CompleteAsync(/*lockToken*/ null))
               .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
```

Answer (score 23):

Here is how to create a Message for testing and set the LockToken:

```
var message = new Message();
var systemProperties = message.SystemProperties;
var type = systemProperties.GetType();
var lockToken = Guid.NewGuid();
type.GetMethod("set_LockTokenGuid", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(systemProperties, new object[] { lockToken });
type.GetMethod("set_SequenceNumber", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(systemProperties, new object[] { 0 });
```

I wish that I had been able to come up with something that did not involve reflection.

Comment: nice hack, one small change I've made is adding the `?` operator just before Invoke to avoid a possible NRE

Comment: Thank you *very* much for this! For anyone testing DeliveryCount, it would be `type.GetMethod("set_DeliveryCount",`...